# Why and when we need to add android: prefix to style?

Tags: android, styles, android-theme

> I have seen that some **Style attributes** require `android` prefix and some don't need it. What is the reason. like

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

**Why we haven't use `android:windowActionBar` and `android:windowNoTitle`**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on SDK version Android styles are grouped in different namespaces. In order to override a Theme you have to follow it's namespace.

That's the reason you don't need the `android:` prefix when extending an `AppCompat` Theme, but if you wanted something else, let's say `Theme.Holo` - you'd have 2 different styles for the them - one for pre-Lollipop devices, and one for `-21`, the latter having the `android:` prefix before each style attribute.

Comment: But how do I remember when to add it and when to ignore. For AppCompat doesn't require it always. But if we are using it for Holo like theme we have to create two folder for style.xml one for lolipop without android prefix and one with prefix. Am I right.??

Comment: Yes, 2 different xmls would be used for `Holo` - one in the styles and one in styles-21. I'm not sure if there is a way to tell when you have to do it, but in most cases the IDE would show an error that you require a higher API level and a quick search on SO would help you solve the issue

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which Themes you're using and which context it is. These attributes are defined by different sources.

If the attribute name is prefixed with `android:`, it's a framework attribute and can only be used for the Android versions having it defined.

If the attribute is not prefixed at all, the attributes are defined by your own application. This includes all attribute definitions you pulled in with libraries.

In your example you're defining a theme for `AppCompat` which is part of the support library and thus of your application. The framework widgets won't recognize these colors directly.

Comment: I've faced issues due to this several times and still haven't learned the difference. I don't understand why `android:elevation` works but `elevation` doesn't. And why `cornerRadius` works and `android:cornerRadius` as well.

Comment: @ShivamPokhriyal it always depends on the who's reading the value. So if `elevation` doesn't work, it just means that it is never read as this.

Comment: Yeah, but is there any foolproof way to know in advance whether `android:` prefix is to be used or not?

Comment: Not really, sorry. Maybe you'll find some good documentation for it. I usually read the sources to understand the behavior.

Comment: Ohh okay. FWIW, I used `elevation` for materialChip and it didn't work, but `android:elevation` did.